# Graph query with py2neo OGM

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo, neo4j-ogm

I'm trying to use classes defined using py2neo to run graph queries on my database. Here's what I have so far:

```
py2neo.ogm import Graph, GraphObject, Property, RelatedTo, Label

gsb = Graph(address = "localhost:11004", password='<my_password>')


class Dataset(GraphObject):

    __primarykey__ = 'title'

    title = Property()

    Dataset = Label()


class User(GraphObject):

    __primarykey__ = 'user_id'

    user_id = Property()
    dept = Property()
    email = Property()
    name = Property()
    eigenvector = property()

    grantedAccess = RelatedTo("Dataset", "GRANTED_ACCESS_TO")


test_user = User.match(gsb, 'test_user').first()


for ds in test_user.grantedAccess:
    print(ds.title)
```

What I was hoping for was a list of Datasets to which 'test_user' had been granted access. The equivalent cypher query would be:

```
MATCH (a:User)-[r:GRANTED_ACCESS_TO]->(b:Dataset) 
WHERE a.user_id = 'test_user'
RETURN b.title
```

But when I run the python code I get nothing, not even an error message, just no results. I know the database connection is working correctly, and I know there are relationship patterns in the database that match the query. I'm assuming my query is written incorrectly somehow?

Can anyone explain why my python code returns no results?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why your python code doesn't work; but you know that you can run queries from python, right?

Comment: Yes I do. thanks. I had done that in the first version of my project but ended up with complex string substitutions as I wanted my users to be able to switch search terms.  I was hoping an OGM approach would help simplify the python code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it turns out this was just an embarrassing typo. The database documentation I was working from labeled the edge `GRANTED_ACCESS_TO` but in the actual database it was `GRANTED_ACCESS`. Once I made that change, everything worked as expected.

I'll let the mods decided whether it's worth keeping this question posted as a code example. Otherwise, feel free to delete.